# In ZooKeeper, is there a way to write a hierarchy atomically without implementing distributed locks yourself?

Tags: java, tree, hadoop, atomic, apache-zookeeper

let's say I want to write out this tree to zookeeper

```
.            a
.           / \
.          b   c
.         / \
.        d   e
```

some other client could come along and delete node b right after I create it but before I'm able to write node 'd' or 'e'.

Is there a way I can write this hierarchy atomically, or possibly lock a certain path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the new [multi() API](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.3/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html#multi%28java.lang.Iterable%29)

It completes all the operations or aborts them all.

Answer (score 2):

You can coordinate different clients by either electing a leader or maintaining locks
You can read a nice description on [Zookeeper's recipes](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Recipes) on the Netflix curator docs (which is also a nice library to use if you want to do anything with zookeeper)