# Most efficient way to create a path in zookeeper where root elements of the path may or may not exist?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-zookeeper

Imagine a path "/root/child1/child2/child3"

Imagine in zookeeper that maybe a part of this exists, say "/root/child1"

There is no equivalent of "mkdir -p" in zookeeper; Also, ZooKeeper.multi() will fail if any one operation fails, so a "make path" couldn't really be baked into a multi call.   Additionally, you could have some other client trying to make the same path...

This is what I have come up with for creating a path.  I wonder if it is even worth checking to see if a part exists or not, to save the round trip of the exists() call.

```
//String[] pathParts new String[] { "root", "child1", "child2", "child3" };

public void savePath(String[] pathParts) {
    if (zooKeeper.exists(pathString, false) != null) return;
    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
    for (String pathElement : pathParts) {
        path.append(UNIX_FILE_SEPARATOR).append(pathElement);
        String pathString = path.toString();
        try {
            //bother with the exists call or not?
            if (zooKeeper.exists(pathString, false) == null) {
                zooKeeper.create(pathString, null, ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.PERSISTENT);
            }
        } catch (KeeperException e) {
            if (e.code() != KeeperException.Code.NODEEXISTS)
                throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?   Assuming that a) you don't know ahead of time how much of the path already exists and b) some other client might be trying to write the same path (and we want to avoid locking).

Comment: Can you give an example of what the instance variable path includes and whats being passed to the pathParts parameter? A bit confused about the code as its appending path back to itself.

Comment: sorry - had some mistakes in that.  fixed now, more or less.

Comment: Isn't there a fundamental problem with any solution in the style of if (!zooKeeper.exists) then (zooKeeper.create), that another client may create the path between those two calls? Similarly, if we do try(create) catch(){it exists already}, another client may delete the node after our create and before any next call we do assuming it already exists. Those sorts of 'race conditions' are exactly what we'd want our distributed systems to be resilient for...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An exist call can be made with 1 round trip from the server to the client.

A create call has the same round trip, but create is a write operation that entails a couple more round trips between the servers in the zk cluster, so a create is a little more expensive that an exist.

So the total time for your algorithm is,

Time for 1 read op * Probability node already exists + (Time for 1 write op) * (1 - Probability the node already exists).

So either of `if(!exist()) create()` vs `create()` could be faster.  In the end it probably doesn't matter.

If you want to be really fast, you can use the async api so that you can create all the components of your path without waiting for the server to respond to requests 1 by 1.

```
final AtomicBoolean success = new AtomicBoolean(false);
final CountdownLatch latch = new CountdownLatch(1);
StringCallback cb = new StringCallback() {
    processResult(int rc, String path, Object ctx, String name) {
        if(name.equals(pathString ) {
            //wait for the last path
            success.set(rc == KeeperException.Code.NODEEXISTS ||
                        rc == KeeperException.Code.OK);
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }
};

StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
for (String pathElement : pathParts) {
    path.append(UNIX_FILE_SEPARATOR).append(pathElement);
    String pathString = path.toString();
    //send requests to create all parts of the path without waiting for the
    //results of previous calls to return
    zooKeeper.create(pathString, null, ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.PERSISTENT, cb);
}
latch.await();
if(!success.get()) { 
    throw ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a guarantee that those asynchronous requests are handled in the order in which they are requested? Because if not, possibly due to one request having more network delay than the next or whatever reason, this solution might end up trying to create a child node while the request to create the parent node is stil to reach the server, so that would fail.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [Netflix's curator](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki) library which makes using zookeeper much simpler

```
client.create().withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT).forPath("/root/child1/child2/child3", new byte[0]).withACL(ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE).creatingParentsIfNeeded();
```

Comment: but is this any more efficient than above, or does it just hide it?

Comment: take a look at EnsurePath (https://github.com/Netflix/curator/blob/master/curator-client/src/main/java/com/netflix/curator/utils/EnsurePath.java) and ZKPaths (https://github.com/Netflix/curator/blob/master/curator-client/src/main/java/com/netflix/curator/utils/ZKPaths.java) and decide for yourself

Comment: same number of network calls, but even worse because they have a synchronized block.  I'm going to open a ticket with the zookeeper folks asking them for an atomic path creation call.

Comment: Using version 2.9.0, it would be `client.create().creatingParentContainersIfNeeded().withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT).withACL(ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE).forPath("/root/child1/child2/child3");`

Comment: You can also do `client.checkExists().creatingParentContainersIfNeeded().forPath("/someapp/somemodule/someroute")` if you just want to ensure that the path exists