# How to create multiple znodes at once?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Despite we have a znode named `'my-node'`

I want to create this structure : `/my-node/node-level-1/node-level-2..`

`create` command will throw an error because of missing node of `node-level-1`.

How to create all missing nodes with one command automatically, like we do it for directories with `mkdir -p`

Documentation doesn't say anything about it. Is it impossible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I recursively create a path in Zookeeper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340756/can-i-recursively-create-a-path-in-zookeeper)